# Can I promote an earlier version in the Kynetx Appbuilder?

Tags: krl

I changed one of my applications (for April Fools) but I'd like to go back to the previous version and make it the development version. Is there any way to do this in Appbuilder, or do I have to manually undo all the changes I made?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way will probably be to

- go to the deploy page in appbuilder
- click on the view link of the version you want to revert to
  [image]
- copy the code 
  [image]
- past code into appbuilder edit window and save

Unfortunately there isn't a revert function yet. This is easy enough to do by hand and doesn't happen enough to make me think that it will be added soon.